# Flair for TeX only still uses old icon

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design

The newly designed icon {} did not make it to the flair picture. Or maybe I need to update it somehow, and do not know how?

Hmmm. Here's mine:

[image: profile for Yossi Farjoun at TeX - LaTeX, Q&A for expert users of TeX, LaTeX and other related typesetting systems]

Comment: Which URL for the flair are you using?  I think there are three different schemes at the moment.

Comment: I updated my question to reflect what I mean...

Comment: OK. it's fixed now. it took a bit more the 24 hours....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can take up to 24 hours for flair to update, so you may need to be a bit more patient..

Answer (score 2):

Are you talking about the user flair like:

[image]

I'm seeing the latest favicon.

Comment: yes, but mine shows the old one...see in my question